# On which IP is teamcity running my docker images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, teamcity

I'm setting up a local teamcity and I want to load my selenium grid via teamcity. So I created underneath docker compose file. Everything works and it seems that it's running only I cannot find it with the correct ip. Does anybody know where I need to look for the correct ip?

```
version: '2'
services:
    firefox:
        image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
        ports:
            - "6900:6900"
        volumes:
            - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
        depends_on:
            - hub
        environment:
            HUB_HOST: hub
    firefoxTest:
        image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
        ports:
            - "6901:6901"
        volumes:
            - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
        depends_on:
            - hub
        environment:
            HUB_HOST: hub
    firefoxTesting:
        image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
        ports:
            - "6902:6902"
        volumes:
            - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
        depends_on:
            - hub
        environment:
            HUB_HOST: hub
    chrome:
        image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
        ports:
            - "5900:5900"
        volumes:
            - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
        depends_on:
            - hub
        environment:
            HUB_HOST: hub
    hub:
        image: selenium/hub
        ports:
            - "4444:4444"
```

Comment: have you tried `docker inspect <container-name-here>` ?

Comment: What is your host OS?

Comment: My host is windows @Mihai

Comment: @HamidAli When I do that docker says that no object of that name exists. But when I run the build on teamcity again i complains as it is already running

Comment: Can you show us the command which you ran?

Comment: Docker on Windows is always tricky. It runs in a VM either Hyper V or VirtualBox. You need to check the IP of that  VM and make sure it have a network interface connected to host. Then you need to use the IP of that VM to access your containers

Comment: @HamidAli I run following command: docker inspect seleniumgrid_hub_1

Comment: @Mihai When I run this in commandline their is no issue I go to the ip and it just shows but in teamcity I don't get anything on the same IP